# Babel_traverse: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type

Tags: nestjs, babeljs

I'm running into the problem mentioned in the title with my Nest.JS project. It appeared after one small commit (nothing special, just updates return types in methods), but when I rolled back all changes it is still remaining. I can't figure out where I have to dig to fix this issue. Also the issue appears only during docker compose build at `nest build` command. Locally all works perfect: build, debug, start commands work as expected. Full error log:

```
 node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:297:72 - error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
15:55:52    Type 'NodePath<T>' is not assignable to type 'NodePath<Node>'.
15:55:52      Types of property 'hasNode' are incompatible.
15:55:52        Type '() => this is NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to type '() => this is NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52          Type predicate 'this is NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to 'this is NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52            Type 'NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to type 'NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52              Types of property 'unshiftContainer' are incompatible.
15:55:52                Type '<Nodes extends Node | readonly Node[]>(listKey: keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }, nodes: Nodes) => NodePaths<...>' is not assignable to type '<Nodes extends Node | readonly Node[]>(listKey: "range" | "leadingComments" | "trailingComments" | "innerComments", nodes: Nodes) => NodePaths<Nodes>'.
15:55:52                  Types of parameters 'listKey' and 'listKey' are incompatible.
15:55:52                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }'.
15:55:52                      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }'.
15:55:52                        Type '"range"' is not assignable to type '(NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never) | (NonNullable<T>["type"] extends any[] ? "type" : never) | (NonNullable<T>["leadingComments"] extends any[] ? "leadingComments" : never) | ... 6 more ... | (NonNullable<...>["extra"] extends any[] ? "extra" : never)'.
15:55:52  
15:55:52  297     findParent<T extends t.Node>(callback: (path: NodePath) => path is NodePath<T>): NodePath<T> | null;
15:55:52                                                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~
15:55:52  node_modules/@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts:305:66 - error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
15:55:52    Type 'NodePath<T>' is not assignable to type 'NodePath<Node>'.
15:55:52      Types of property 'hasNode' are incompatible.
15:55:52        Type '() => this is NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to type '() => this is NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52          Type predicate 'this is NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to 'this is NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52            Type 'NodePath<NonNullable<T>>' is not assignable to type 'NodePath<NonNullable<Node>>'.
15:55:52              Types of property 'unshiftContainer' are incompatible.
15:55:52                Type '<Nodes extends Node | readonly Node[]>(listKey: keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }, nodes: Nodes) => NodePaths<...>' is not assignable to type '<Nodes extends Node | readonly Node[]>(listKey: "range" | "leadingComments" | "trailingComments" | "innerComments", nodes: Nodes) => NodePaths<Nodes>'.
15:55:52                  Types of parameters 'listKey' and 'listKey' are incompatible.
15:55:52                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }'.
15:55:52                      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof { [P in keyof NonNullable<T> as NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never]: P; }'.
15:55:52                        Type '"range"' is not assignable to type '(NonNullable<T>[P] extends any[] ? P : never) | (NonNullable<T>["type"] extends any[] ? "type" : never) | (NonNullable<T>["leadingComments"] extends any[] ? "leadingComments" : never) | ... 6 more ... | (NonNullable<...>["extra"] extends any[] ? "extra" : never)'.
15:55:52  
15:55:52  305     find<T extends t.Node>(callback: (path: NodePath) => path is NodePath<T>): NodePath<T> | null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using version `7.21.0` on `@babel/core` devDependency worked just right for me. Mind the version without `^`. In case you are using only `@babel/traverse` try an older version too.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. The problem was in babel itself. They released a patch with this error but for now it has fixed already.

Comment: No problem and good to hear! I'll take notes :)